# Understanding free product groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory, free-product

I am trying to understand free product groups and I considered the group
$G=\langle a,b|a^2b^{-3}\rangle$. As in this group $a^2=b^3$, it seems like every element of G can be written as $b^{n_1}ab^{n_2}a\ldots$, as every $a$ to a power greater than 2 "disappears" into a power of b. Hence i feel like $G$ is the free product $\mathbb{Z} \star C_2$ where $C_2$ is the cyclic group of order 2. It appears that my intuition is probably false as a similar reasoning would lead to say that it is also the free group $\mathbb{Z}\star C_3$. Can someone explain me why my intuition is false ?

Comment: Your intuition is false because "disappears into a power of another element" is not the same as "becomes the identity element." Although, $c=a^2=b^3$ does generate the group's center, and modding out by $\langle c\rangle$ does yield $C_2\ast C_3$. Note your group is the braid group $B_3$, and the quotient by its center is $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: Your correspondence between elements of $G$ and elements of $\mathbb{Z} * C_2$ is a bijection on the underlying set level, but it is not an isomorphism of groups.

Comment: Use `$\langle X\mid R\rangle$` for $\langle X\mid R\rangle$.

Comment: [More details on @runway44 comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group#Relation_between_B3_and_the_modular_group)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I think I understood !